# Getting specific element in Url using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have this kind of html structure :

```
 <table class="list">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="club.do?codeClub=01670001&millesime=2015"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get the link contained in the second `<td>` of each `<tr>` contained in the `table` that has the `class list`. 
Then actually in each Url I am only interested in the value of the codeclub :
codeClub=01670001

How can I achieve this using Nokogiri ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the anchor tag `a` using nokogiri like so:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<-HTML_END)
 <table class="list">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="club.do?codeClub=01670001&millesime=2015"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
HTML_END

link = doc.css('table.list tbody tr td:nth-child(2) a')[0]['href']
 => "club.do?codeClub=01670001&millesime=2015"
```

Then you can use regular expressions to get the entire query param of codeClub like so:

```
link[/codeClub=([^&]*)/].gsub('codeClub=', '')
 => "01670001"
```

Comment: In the end I used this to access the link:
`links = html_body.css('.list').xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]")`
and then used your regexp to extract the queryparam